# Show one folder up's file if file is not found in current folder htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to write a simple **`.htaccess`** script to do the following task:

- there is a folder with documents in `http://www.website.com/files/documents/`
- this folder contains some `subfolders` called such as `images`, `sheets`, `texts` etc.
- there can be some documents both in the `main folder` and `subfolders`

**The following must happen:**

- User requests `http://www.website.com/files/documents/images/image1.jpg` and the file does not exist --> user is redirected one directory up to `http://www.website.com/files/documents/image1.jpg` where the file exists
- User requests `http://www.website.com/files/documents/sheets/excel.xls` and the file does not exist --> user is redirected one directory up to `http://www.website.com/files/documents/excel.xls`

> **Note:** It should be valid for all folder names and independent of number of path

**Example:**

`www.example.com/one/two/three/four/3.jpg`

`www.example.com/one/two/three/2.jpg`

`www.example.com/one/two/three/four/five/4.jpg`

**Here's the code that i tried:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?/)?[^/]+/(.+)$ $1$2 [L]
```

It worked for 2 level folder but didn't work for 3 level or more folder.

`www.example.com/one/two/1.jpg` => **worked**

`www.example.com/one/two/three/2.jpg` => **didn't worked**

`www.example.com/one/two/three/four/3.jpg` => **didn't worked** and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to make your regex ungreedy, you want it to eat up all of the folders up until the last one. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?[^/]+/([^/]+)$ $1$2 [L]
```